# Tabbing in and out of Java applet on web page

Tags: java, applet, focus, tab-ordering

I have a Java applet with several focusable elements that is embedded in a web page.

Is it possible to make the elements in the applet part of the logical tab order of the rest of the page?

To clarify: I would like to use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move from an element outside the applet to the first element of the applet and then use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to move back to the element outside the applet. Similarly I would like to use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move from the last element of the applet to the next element of the web-page and use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to move back.

Answer (score 4):

You can define the tab order within your page by attaching `tabindex` attributes to your elements, *including* your applet’s `object` element. You can define the tab order within your applet by extending the [`FocusTraversalPolicy` class](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#customFocusTraversal).

Let’s say you have three page controls — **A**, **B**, and **C** — the second of which — **B** — is your applet, and three applet controls — **X**, **Y**, and **Z**. If you make controls **A**, **B**, and **C** `tabindex` `1`, `2`, and `3` and **X**, **Y**, and **Z** first through third in the traversal cycle, your effective tab order will be: **A**, **X**, **Y**, **Z**, **C**.

Comment: tabIndex on applet tags does not behaves consistently across browsers. On IE7 lets me tab into the applet, but I cannot tab back out. Firefox lets me tab into the applet, but does not give focus to the applet's controls. Chrome ignores the applet in the taborder despite the tabIndex. I do not see any way of indicating in the FocusTraversalPolicy that I want (to use your example) to move focus outside the applet after Z. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: @Rasmus Faber: AFAIK, you're not missing anything. Applets simply aren't designed to be a part of the web page, but rather a mini application (hence the name) embedded on the page.

Comment: I disagree that applets aren’t designed to be part of the page. According to the HTML spec, “tabindex” ought to be supported by “object” tags <http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex>. So the approach I described ought to work unless the browsers are behaving badly. Unfortunately, it appears they are — I just tried the whole shebang out and reproduced the inconsistent behavior across browsers. In which case Rasmus, I’m afraid you’re, as the French might say, “shit out of luck”.